# Observable collection of tuples how to mark an item as non serializable

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, tuples, observablecollection

I have a collection of tuples

```
ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, object, object>> oc = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, object, object>>();
```

in which I want the user to be able to add and use new items.
But then when it comes to serializing, only the first two items are important.
So the last one has not to be recorded on file system.

Of course this is not a biggie since I can cycle on all elements and put them to null but I was wondering if I could do that automatically.

Thank you in advance

--ADD--
What comes to my mind now is making a class MyTuple3 which inherits from the Tuple class and in which only the first two elements are marked as serializables. That being said still searching for something better.

Comment: Your idea in the end sounds about right. Not sure why you need Tuple or inherit from it, custom type should do the job nicely here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but why don't you do something like

```
var toSerialize = oc.Take(2);
```

And then serialite toSerialize

Comment: Why downvoting? Not the best solution perhaps but is it wrong?

Comment: @Patrick, it depends on what your question is about: serializing specific amount of items in the collection or serializing specific properties of those items.

Comment: The solution can be not general. I have a various list of tuples of 3 elements and have to cases: CASE (A) I have to serialize all the elements of the tuples item1, item2, item3. CASE (B) I have to serialize only two elements so item1 e item2. In short in case B when I deserialize all elements are to be null.

Comment: @unkreativ your solution could do the trick. I have to test if this works: prior to serializing I do oc= oc.Take(2);